# move duplicates to the end of array in c while preserving order - nlogn

Tags: c

I am stuck in this question for long time.
the question is - to move duplicates to the end of the array while preserving the order(time complexity must be O(nlogn)).
limitation:

- order must be preserved.
- can use only 1 helper array
- the range of values in the array are not known and can be really large from n(which is the size fo the array).
- values are positives.
- time complexity - nlogn

example:
arr = {7, 3, 1, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2, 5, 9, 6, 2}, n = 12
result:
arr = {7, 3, 1, 2, 9, 5, 6, 2, 9, 2, 3, 7}

this what i did right now but i am stuck from thier:

- copied original array to temp array
- sort the temp array using quick sort
- move duplicate to the end in temp array

i know that i need to do some comparison with the original array but this the part that i am stuck.

code:

```
int findDulpilcatesV2(int* arr, int n) {
    int i, * tempArr, j = 0, countNonRepeatEl = 0, searchKeyIndex, elIndex;

    tempArr = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(tempArr);

    // Saving original array in temp array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = arr[i];
    }

    // Sorting temp array
    quickSort(tempArr, 0, n - 1);

    // Move duplicates to the end
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (tempArr[i] != tempArr[i+1])
        {
            swap(&tempArr[j], &tempArr[i]);
            countNonRepeatEl++;
            j++;
        }
    }


    free(tempArr);
    tempArr = NULL;
    return countNonRepeatEl;
}
```

Comment: If you discard the duplicates in the temp array, you can search for any value in log n time, giving you an index that could be used with another temp array.  If you know you've already seen "7" once, you know what to do with any "7"s later on.

Comment: @DaveS thanks, so i need to do binary search on the sorted side of the temp array - the key will be each element from the original array  - than how should o do the swap ?

Comment: I think you need to play games with the signs of the numbers. Imagine that the original array contains `{7, 3, 1, 2, -7, 9, -3, -2, 5, -9, 6, -2}`. Now you can easily solve the problem by copying positive numbers to the beginning of the helper array, and negative numbers to the end.

Comment: my thought was to use a third marker array of Booleans, that start as false then flip to true once a number has been matched once, but I missed "can use only 1 helper array".   Since you know all of the original numbers are positive you can use @user3386109's idea of setting the matches in the temp array negative instead, and using abs( temp array element ) in the binary search

Comment: @DaveS thanks i will try this - one more question  - am i doing the swap right ?

Comment: You don't need to keep the duplicates in the temp array, you just need to go from 0 to n-1 and copy all the unique values, then use j as the new n.  so `t[j] = t[i]` instead of swapping.  You need to be careful about i = 0 and/or i = (n-1) so that you are not trying to read [-1] or [n].  That's for my idea which is to make temp unique then to compact the main array in place using binary search on temp and flipping the sign in temp

Comment: Question - is this wrong?  "7" is the first duplicate so preserving order wouldn't it be the first value after the run of unique numbers? - `example: arr = {7, 3, 1, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2, 5, 9, 6, 2}, n = 12 result: arr = {7, 3, 1, 2, 9, 5, 6, 2, 9, 2, 3, 7}`  It looks like the order of the duplicates has been reversed.  Ahhh, that is when you need to swap, to modify the main array in place you swap duplicates to (n-1) then (n-2), (n-3), ... .  No swapping needed in the helper, but it is needed in the main or the results will be messed up

Comment: @DaveS still can't figure it out how to implement , can you write some code sample or modify my code please

Comment: Please edit / update your question to show your progress, and where you are stuck.  Are you using logging or a debugger to test what parts are working?  If I write a solution you'll miss out on learning how to solve it, and the next assignment will be harder to finish.  Logging and debugging are very important skills for developers.